# Pandas: Drop row based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, I want to drop all the rows where flag=1 repeatedly towards the tail end of dataframe. Below is what I am doing which is not giving exact output, whats wrong?:

```
import pandas as pd

# Assuming df is your DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'employeeid': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    'date': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03'],
    'flag': [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df.sort_values(by=['employeeid', 'date'], ascending=False, inplace=True)

mask = df.groupby('employeeid')['flag'].transform(lambda x: x[::-1].cumsum().eq(len(x)) & (x.iloc[-1] == 1)).astype(bool)

df = df[~mask]
```

Expected output:

```
  employeeid        date  flag
0           1  2022-01-01     0
5           3  2022-01-01     0
6           3  2022-01-02     0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use a simple [`groupby.cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummax.html):

```
df[df.loc[::-1, 'flag'].ne(1).groupby(df['employeeid']).cummax()[::-1]]
```

Or if you only have one stretch of 1s:

```
df[~df['flag'].eq(1).groupby(df['employeeid']).cummax()]
```

Output:

```
   employeeid       date  flag
0           1 2022-01-01     0
5           3 2022-01-01     0
6           3 2022-01-02     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GroupBy.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cummax.html) with double invert position of rows:

```
out = df[df[::-1].groupby('employeeid')['flag'].cummax().eq(0)[::-1]]
print (out)
   employeeid       date  flag
6           3 2022-01-02     0
5           3 2022-01-01     0
0           1 2022-01-01     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'employeeid': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    'date': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03'],
    'flag': [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.sort_values(by=['employeeid', 'date'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
mask = df[::-1].groupby('employeeid')['flag'].cummax().eq(1)
new_df = df[~mask]
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   employeeid       date  flag
6           3 2022-01-02     0
5           3 2022-01-01     0
0           1 2022-01-01     0
```